# How to write regex in solr query for "fixed string"

Tags: solr, solrj

How to write regex in solr query for "fixed string":

```
e.g: [{
"field":"Text input"
},{
"field":"Text input only"
},{
"field":"Search Text input"
} ]
```

Need to write a query on "Text input" phrase -> it will return only first object.
So, im trying to write `q=field:"Text input"` -> it is returning all three but my requiremnt is retrun excat match i.e. first object only.

Answer (score 2):

if we need above kind search we should create string type of field in schema creation instead of TextField below is the difference on search

String stores a word/sentence as an exact string without performing tokenization etc. Commonly useful for storing exact matches, e.g, for facetting.

Text typically performs tokenization, and secondary processing (such as lower-casing etc.). Useful for all scenarios when we want to match part of a sentence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).